# Force Close When Clicking List Item. (Android)

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 2.1 NullPointerException with TabWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023289/android-2-1-nullpointerexception-with-tabwidgets)

I have developed an Android application which shows a list of targets in list view, then after clicking on one of the list item it opens a tab widget having 3 tabs (Details, Map, Photo) 
application is developed for api 7. and is working fine on all devices devices having api 8 and above. But when i open the same application on Micromax a60 having android 2.1.1
It is getting force close.

below is the log cat i got after force close. I have tried understanding it but failed. Now if this issue is not solved i will have to upgrade micromax a60 to 2.2.

Can anyone please help me with this issue ?

```
    01-18 12:42:36.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2505): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw(TabWidget.java:206)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1837)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    01-18 12:42:36.387: E/AndroidRuntime(2505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-18 12:42:36.407: E/dalvikvm(2505): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Another thing is that this list view is in one of the tabs of tab widget.
and it is also opening a tab widget. Can this be a problem ? maybe..

This method is called when list item is clicked:

```
    private void showTargetReport(String result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityUnreadReportListForEmployee.this,
            ActivityTargetDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra("TARGET_DETAILS", result);
    if (other_target)
        intent.putExtra("OTHER_TARGET", true);
    else
        intent.putExtra("OTHER_TARGET", false);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this method is called when ActivityTargetDetails.class is opened

```
    private void showTabs() {
        try {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myContext = this;
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables

    tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    /**********************************************************************/

    if (other_target) {
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be
        // reused)
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this,
                ActivityTargetInfoOtherTarget.class);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", employeeDetails);
        intent.putExtra("TARGET_DETAILS", targetDetails);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Target Details")
                .setIndicator("Details",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.details))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    } else {
        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be
        // reused)
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityTargetInfo.class);
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_DETAILS", employeeDetails);
        intent.putExtra("TARGET_DETAILS", targetDetails);
        intent.putExtra("LOCATION_DETAILS", locationDetails);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Target Details")
                .setIndicator("Details",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.details))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    /*********************************************************************/

    // Do the same for the Map Tab
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityMapView.class);

    double targetLatitude = 0.0;
    double targetLongitude = 0.0;
    double distanceDifference = 0.0;
    double timeSpent = 0.0;
    double feedbackLatitude = 0.0;
    double feedbackLongitude = 0.0;

    try {
        if (other_target) {
            targetLatitude = Double
                    .parseDouble(targetObject
                            .getString(API_Handler.OTHER_TARGET_TABLE_LATITUDE));
        } else {
            targetLatitude = Double
                    .parseDouble(locationObject
                            .getString(API_Handler.LOCATION_TABLE_LOCATION_LAT));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        targetLatitude = 0.0;
    }

    try {
        if (other_target) {
            targetLongitude = Double
                    .parseDouble(targetObject
                            .getString(API_Handler.OTHER_TARGET_TABLE_LONGITUDE));
        } else {
            targetLongitude = Double
                    .parseDouble(locationObject
                            .getString(API_Handler.LOCATION_TABLE_LOCATION_LONG));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        targetLongitude = 0.0;
    }

    try {
        distanceDifference = Double
                .parseDouble(targetObject
                        .getString(API_Handler.TARGET_TABLE_TARGET_DISTANCE_DIFFERENCE));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        distanceDifference = 0.0;
    }

    try {
        timeSpent = Double.parseDouble(targetObject
                .getString(API_Handler.TARGET_TABLE_TARGET_TIME_SPENT));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        timeSpent = 0.0;
    }

    try {
        if (other_target) {
            feedbackLatitude = targetLatitude;
        } else {
            feedbackLatitude = Double.parseDouble(targetObject
                    .getString(API_Handler.TARGET_TABLE_TARGET_LAT));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        feedbackLatitude = 0.0;
    }

    try {
        if (other_target) {
            feedbackLongitude = targetLongitude;
        } else {
            feedbackLongitude = Double.parseDouble(targetObject
                    .getString(API_Handler.TARGET_TABLE_TARGET_LONG));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        feedbackLongitude = 0.0;
    }

    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_TARGET_LATITUDE,
            targetLatitude);
    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_TARGET_LONGITUDE,
            targetLongitude);
    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_DISTANCE_DIFFERENCE,
            distanceDifference);
    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_TIME_SPENT, timeSpent);
    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_FEEDBACK_LATITUDE,
            feedbackLatitude);
    mapIntent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_FEEDBACK_LONGITUDE,
            feedbackLongitude);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map")
            .setIndicator("Map", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.map))
            .setContent(mapIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    /**************************************************************************/

    // Do the same for the photo tab
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityPhoto.class);
    intent.putExtra(API_Handler.PARAMETER_TARGET_IMAGE_PATH, imagePath);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photo")
            .setIndicator("Photo", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.photo))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Add Some Code where  you are facing the force close

Comment: Here's a question that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023289/android-2-1-nullpointerexception-with-tabwidgets

Comment: The logs indicate the problem lies in the Android source. Maybe it was a bug that was fixed in API 8?

Comment: LawrenceChoy Ok just a minute i will add the source code, Where i am facing force close.

JasonRobinson: I am having the same doubt.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Sorry but i am not sure what code to add, I will add another thing that i think might be reason. Please see the question.

Comment: @dreamer According to logcat the error comes from `at android.widget.TabWidget.dispatchDraw`, which means you have already fired the intent and creating the second activity. So you can provide us code about how you fire the intent, and how you construct your second activity.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy Shared Code, Please Check.